# Permission Denied by Google Cloud Datastore API when accessing from Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-datastore

We have created a Google Apps script, that is supposed to look-up in the Google Cloud Datastore for certain record keys, and if they do not exist, begin a transaction and commit these records.

The script did work successfully with the service-account and the datastoreID of the Google Cloud project MYAPP-TEST, but when we changed the settings to the service-account and datastoreID of the actual Google Cloud project MYAPP-LIVE, only the **lookup** request works successfully with the expected response, but the **beginTransaction** request always results in an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
             {
                  "domain": "global",
                  "reason": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
                  "message": "Unauthorized."
             }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Unauthorized."
     }
}
```

My question is, why does the one request succeed and the other request fails for one datastore (MYAPP-LIVE), while everything (and more) works flawless with the other datastore (MYAPP-TEST). We tried to replicate the settings for both datastores, but maybe we are missing something. So, these is what we have done and the setup. Maybe you have an idea what would explain the different behavior of the script.

MYAPP-LIVE has been created years ago in the old App Engine admin pages and uses custom domains, the same as we have in our Google Apps for Work domain. MYAPP-TEST was created a few weeks ago in the new Google Cloud console. Both have a datastore. The way how both projects have been created are different and no custom domain is used for MYAPP-TEST, that should be the only differences I can think of.

The script uses [Google Cloud Datastore API 1beta2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/).

The **lookup** request is sent to:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/"+datasetId+"/lookup?fields=deferred%2Fpath%2Fname%2Cfound"
```

with some keys in payload, which I think is irrelevant here.

The **beginTransaction** request is sent to:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/"+datasetId+"/beginTransaction"
```

with `{payload:{"isolationLevel": "SNAPSHOT"}}` stringified.

Both requests also use these options:

```
var options = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType : "application/json" ,
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    headers: {
        "authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    }
}
```

Both requests use the same `accessToken`, which is retrieved through [Google Samples Apps Script oAuth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) for authentication.

In both projects, MYAPP-LIVE and MYAPP-TEST, we had created service-accounts with the editor-role and with the option *Domain-wide Delegation* turned on. This was done in Google Cloud Developer console under `Home > Permissions`

The downloaded P12 JSON is used in the script like this:

```
var keyObj = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "MYAPP-TEST",
    "private_key_id": "149b.............3536d",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n40c4......be321==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "srvacct4gas@myapp-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1033..........6420",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/srvacct4gas%40myapp-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
};
```

The P12 JSON was replaced with that of the service account in MYAPP-LIVE.

In Google Cloud Developer console under `Home > API`, we also turned on Google Cloud Datastore API and (not sure if really needed) Google Drive API.

In Google Apps for Work, Admin page [Manage API client access](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients), we also added the service-account of MYAPP-LIVE, the same way we did earlier with MYAPP-TEST, that is with the **Client ID** copied from the service account and these scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

In addition, we changed the Google Apps script's Developer Console project number of MYAPP-TEST to the number of MYAPP-LIVE (in the script menu: `Resources > Developers Console Project ...`

Finally, I also have reversed the sequence of the requests, first the **beginTransaction**, but it fails again with the same error.

Comment: I have found another difference, and when I changed it, the script works fine with MYAPP-LIVE, too. In Google Cloud Console, under `App Engine > Settings` there is an option `Application Settings > Referrers`. It was set to `Google Apps domain: MYDOMAIN.COM`. After changing it to `Google Accounts API` (as in MYAPP-TEST), the script now behaves as expected. Any idea, why the authentication method of App Engine would impact only certain request types to the Google Cloud Datastore API?